# How can I horizontally align these divs in the centre?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got some items that I'm attempting to align horizontally and vertically in the centre of my site page, using Twitter Bootstrap, so that it is mobile responsive but it won't align horizontally.

[image]

I'm sure its got something to do with the combination of images, ul list and p tags. What can I try next?

HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="trial">
    <div class="span4">

        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <div align="center">
            <img src="http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/socialmediatoo.png" width="150" height="auto"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <div align="center">
            <ul class="testli">
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">FAQ's</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">Work With Us</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="http://mysite/information">Privacy Policy<br></a></li>
                <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.drinkaware.co.uk/"><div id="drinkaware"></div></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <div align="center">
            <div id="test-div">
                <p>become a driver</p>
                <p>As an ever evolving new start up we'll constantly be looking for friendly drivers to join the team, so If you'd be interested in  join our team click the button below to see the available opportunities we have available.</p>
                <input type="submit" id="test-btn" value="FIND OUT MORE" onclick="location='http://mysite/join-the-team/'"/>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
            <div align="center">
            <img src="http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/open247.png" width="150" height="auto"/>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#social-logo {
    width: 180px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/DEVO_socialmediatoo.png');
    background-size: 140px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
#trial {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
}
#drinkaware {
    width: 156px;
    height: 50px;
  display:list-item;
    background-image: url('http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/DrinkawareRed.png');
    background-size: 150px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    vertical-align: top;
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
#open24 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    background-image: url('http://mysite/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/open247.png');
    background-size: 250px auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: display:flexbox might be of use here.

Comment: On the first, most outer div?

Comment: @Maharkus `display: flex`

Comment: @gcampbell where exactly should it be?

Comment: Any chance you can demo this?

Comment: use display:table and table cell for more details see https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Generally putting `display:flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` on the parent element centers the children elements horizontally and vertically. I don't know if there might be some CSS interfering with it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @gcampbell yes you're right, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flexbox and add justify-content property rule. I wrote you a bin [here](http://jsbin.com/yiyufomili/edit?html,css)

```
.block {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: This would be more helpful if you included some of the code in the answer instead of just the link.